# curvilinear coordinates

Tags: cylindrical-coordinates

(A) describe the coordinate surfaces and coordinate curves for the system $x^2-y^2=2u_1\cos(u_2)$, $xy=u_1\sin(u_2)$, $z=u_3$.

(B) show the system is orthogonal

(C) determine $J(x,y,z)/(u1,u2,u3)$ for the system

(D) show that $u_1$ and $u_2$ are related to the cylindrical coordinate Roe and phi and determine the relationship

Comment: (a) Please use MathJax. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference (b) What have you tried? What are your own thoughts on these questions? You've got to demonstrate some effort on your part in order to get further help.

Comment: By definition x^2-y^2=2*u1*cos(u2) is a hyperbolic Paraboloid and how that be related to a cylindrical coordinate. Does it mean to transform it into cylindrical coordinate system?

Comment: Usually different coordinate systems are presented in Cartesian coordinate, namely showing x=.. y=.., so I tried to solve x, y,z separately, then I get 4 different values just for y alone, I know this is not right.

Comment: By setting x^2-y^2=2*u, x*y=v & z=u3. Now u, v &z will replace x, y & z in defining position vector r=ui + vj +zk, then e1=partial r/partial u1, e2=partial r/partial u2..., e1 dot e2=e1 dot e3=e2 dot e3=0, this system is orthogonal. When I use same r to find scale factor h1=1, h2=u1,h3=1, so Jacobian is u1, the answer is 1/2 , where is the mistake. I know I used substitution and I need to return to original form, but how? When I use matrices to find Jacobian I get 2*u1, where is the mistake?